# Returning result to eax (IA-32 Assembly language)

Tags: assembly, intel, x86

I'm slightly confused as to how to return a value from a method in assembly language. As far as I know, the eax register is used to hold the result that is to be returned.

As an example, say my result is 4 and I use:

```
mov eax, 4
```

I now have 4 in eax and I want to return this method. Is there anything I need to do or will the instruction `ret` automatically return the result?

The thing is that I don't know what's so special about register `eax` since when I use `ret` I go back to the caller, and the caller is free to access any of the registers I stored the result to, so why I couldn't just have used `ebx` or `ecx` with the result stored instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason the result is stored in `eax` is convention; you can decide to store it in whatever register you like. However, the caller of your function is likely to assume that the content of the return value is stored in `eax`. This also implies that you don't have to do any extra work when calling `ret`.

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is a [convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) used by at least the Microsoft compilers. There's nothing particular about `eax` in itself. If your assembly language function is called by C/C++ code compiled with one of the normal calling conventions, it will expect the result to be passed in `eax`.

`ret` merely returns control to the point where your function was called. No registers are affected (except for `ESP` and the instruction pointer, of course).

Comment: I thought this particular convention was a bit more widespread, including more than GCC. Do you know of any common compilers which don't use this convention?

Comment: Nope. But anything's possible with conventions.

Comment: @Mr. Shickadance: while not exactly conventional (you can't call them from user code), some Delphi compiler helpers use ZF to return a boolean result.